# Associativity of convolution using Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral.

Tags: probability, integration, stochastic-processes, convolution, stieltjes-integral

*A First Course in Stochastic Processes* (Karlin, S.) defines, for increasing, right-continous functions $A,B$ with $A(0)=B(0)=0$, the convolution $A*B$ as

$$A*B(t)=\int_0^t B(t-y)dA(y).$$

In addition, for any function $c(t)$ (assumed reasonably smooth and bounded on finite intervals) it defines $B*c$ as

$$B*c(t)=\int_0^t c(t-y)dB(y).$$

It then states that the following is easy to verify:

$$A*(B*c)=(A*B)*c.$$

I am having trouble proving this statement, in particular due to the notation of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral. Here is what I have:

\begin{align}
A*(B*c)(t)=&\int_0^tB*c(t-y)dA(y)\\
=&\int_0^t\int_0^{t-y}c(t-y-z)dB(z)dA(y).
\end{align}

However, I cannot figure out the steps required to achieve equation with the RHS. If I try to work out the RHS, I obtain:
\begin{align}
(A*B)*c(t)=&\int_0^t c(t-y)d[A*B(y)],
\end{align}
of which I do not know how I should interpret it.